# Error while calculating accuracy of a timeseries model in R (Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double')

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

With this code:

```
#plotting time series from year 1998 to 2008 
    year.time_series <- ts(t_AMOUNT,start = c(1998) , frequency = 12 ) #Monthly 12
    plot(year.time_series)
#splitting the timeseries for further model evaluation 
    train <- window(year.timeseries, start=1998,end=2005)
    test <- window(year.timeseries, start=2005, end=2008)

#using models to check the accuracy results
    etsfit <- ets(train)
    summary(etsfit)

    plot(train, main="ETS Forecast", ylab = "ets(training set)", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
    lines(etsfit$fitted, col="orange")

#forecast
    forecast.ets <- forecast(etsfit, h=24)
    summary(forecast.ets)
    plot(forecast.ets)

    plot(forecast.ets, main = "2 Year Forecast Using ETS Model",
         xlim = c(1998, 2008), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
    lines(test, col="red")

    library(Metrics)
#input = forecast values, actual values
    accuracy(forecast.ets,test)
```

I am getting the following error at `accuracy(forecast.ets,test)`:

> Error in NextMethod(.Generic) :
>          (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In `!=.default`(actual, predicted) :
>          longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Is there a way to split a time series and calculate it's accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `Metrics::accuracy()` rather than `forecast::accuracy()`, which is the function that will accomplish what I think you want. After some explanation of why, I also have some general notes about asking questions on Stack Overflow that might be helpful for you if you have another question for this site in the future.

#### `Metrics::accuracy()` vs. `forecast::accuracy()`

We can see some differences between the functions if we look at the help files (`help("forecast::accuracy")` and `help("Metrics::accuracy")`).

The arguments for forecast accuracy are like

```
accuracy(f, x, test = NULL, d = NULL, D = NULL, ...)
```

where `f` is "An object of class “forecast”, or a numerical vector containing forecasts...." and `x` is "An optional numerical vector containing actual values of the same length as object, or a time series overlapping with the times of f." This matches with how you tried to use it, passing as a first argument a forecast class object and as a second the vector of actual values.

If you're wanting to use `Metrics::accuracy()`, its arguments are like

```
accuracy(actual, predicted)
```

where `actual` is "The ground truth vector, where elements of the vector can be any variable type" and `predicted` is "The predicted vector, where elements of the vector represent a prediction for the corresponding value in actual." In other words, your first argument would have to be **only** the predictions themselves, not all the other information present in a `forecast` object. I also don't think it gives you the type of accuracy metric you'd want with this sort of analysis; it gives "the proportion of elements in actual that are equal to the corresponding element in predicted".

#### Some advice for asking questions in the future

First, I'd check out the great resource, [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Next, I'll give you the code I used to reproduce your issue, and you'll see some changes I had to make to even get started (my comments begin with `###`):

```
#plotting time series from year 1998 to 2008 
### Since we don't have t_AMOUNT, we can't recreate your data
# year.time_series <- ts(t_AMOUNT, start = c(1998), frequency = 12) #Monthly 12
### So I did the following to make some dummy data
set.seed(42)
year.time_series <- ts(rnorm(12*11), start = c(1998), frequency = 12 )
plot(year.time_series)
#splitting the timeseries for further model evaluation
### Since there are spelling changes below for some reason,
### I had to do the next line (or change the variable names below)
year.timeseries <- year.time_series 
train <- window(year.timeseries, start=1998, end=2005)
test <- window(year.timeseries, start=2005, end=2008)

#using models to check the accuracy results
### We need the forecast library for ets(),
### but it wasn't loaded in your code
library(forecast) 
etsfit <- ets(train)
summary(etsfit)

plot(train, main = "ETS Forecast", ylab = "ets(training set)",
     cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
lines(etsfit$fitted, col = "orange")

#forecast
forecast.ets <- forecast(etsfit, h = 24)
summary(forecast.ets)
plot(forecast.ets)

plot(forecast.ets, main = "2 Year Forecast Using ETS Model",
     xlim = c(1998, 2008), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
lines(test, col = "red")

library(Metrics)
#input = forecast values, actual values
accuracy(forecast.ets,test)
forecast::accuracy(forecast.ets, test)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This forecast::accuracy(forecast.ets, test) works.

Comment: @Logica Glad it worked! Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by "click[ing] on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." Cheers!

Comment: i was wondering if you could help me figure out if these result generated from forecast::accuracy() are good or bad ?                                                
Training set   -9307315( ME) 112315906(RMSE)  65976168(MAE) -2760.9186(MPE) 2802.6128(MAPE) 0.6907705(MASE) 0.01781224(ACF1)        NA(Theil's U)
Test set     -117005759(ME) 361431964(RMSE) 264015057(MAE)  -201.7622(MPE)  226.7654(MAPE) 2.7642377(MASE) 0.13804565(ACF1) 0.7776152(Theil's U) respectively? Like on which metrics i have to evaluate the model.